# Cannot get any updates or installs because of server pt.archive.ubuntu.com (193.136.212.166)

Tags: server, apt, updates

So, the terminal always gets stuck when trying to gets the packages from the server: `pt.archive.ubuntu.com` (193.136.212.166).

How can I use another server? This has been like this all day. I asked a friend to try, and he couldn't either. I've done as suggested and ran

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

but it still gets stuck connecting to that server.

```
...
91% [A Ligar a pt.archive.ubuntu.com (193.136.212.166)]
...
```

And then it fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can be changed in this way:

1. Search and open 'Software Sources' ('Software and Updates' in 13.04) in the dash.
2. Choose 'Main Server' as in this image:
   [image: Main Server]
3. Close the window.
4. Retry `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal.

Comment: It solved my issue. Thank you, and sorry for the late appreciation.